# Can one Tcp-Client establish connection to 2 different servers at once?

Tags: sockets, tcpclient, tcpserver

BlokDiagram of my application:

I have a system based on TCP/IP. As you can see on the blokdiagram, the task is to get data from SAP-Server. The client receives files and saves them on known directories, where Gui-App can get access to them.

I need to create a Tcp client, which should receive files from SAP-Server and send them to to Zebra-Printer. The client application need to both transmit data and receive data.
Can I do this in one client application or do i need multiple clients?

I found this code on the internet just for testing.

```
{
int Socket1 = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

sockaddr_in SrcSockAddr;
SrcSockAddr.sin_family = PF_INET;
SrcSockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.2");
SrcSockAddr.sin_port = htons(5061);

if( -1 == bind(Socket1, (sockaddr*) &SrcSockAddr, sizeof (SrcSockAddr)) )
   exit(1);

sockaddr_in DstSockAddr;
DstSockAddr.sin_family = PF_INET;
DstSockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.3");
DstSockAddr.sin_port = htons(5061);

if( connect(Socket1, (sockaddr*)&DstSockAddr, sizeof(DstSockAddr)) )
    exit(2);


int Socket2 = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

if( -1 == bind(Socket2, (sockaddr*) &SrcSockAddr, sizeof (SrcSockAddr)) )
    exit(3);

DstSockAddr.sin_port = htons(5062);
if( connect(Socket2, (sockaddr*)&(DstSockAddr), sizeof(DstSockAddr)) )
    exit(4);

exit(0);
}
```

Cannot figure out what's wrong with it...

Comment: Why do you think there is something wrong?  Are you getting an error?  Unexplained behavior?  You need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one client application with two sockets, one connected to each server.

Comment: Can you check whats wrong with the code i tried (copied it from internet).

Comment: Change it to call perror() after every possible error and you will see for yourself. Just calling exit() for every error is a complete waste of your time, and everybody else's.

Comment: `perror()` does not exist on Windows. Use `WSAGetLastError()` instead, and `FormatMessage()` if you want to retrieve a human readable text message for a given error code.